# Updating to Nuxt3 RC3 produces client side errors

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am out of options to ask for help. I used an older version of nuxt3 and after upgrading to `3.0.0-3c.3`, starting the project with `nuxt dev` results in a broken site, giving me a cryptic error message that I have no idea how to debug:

```
Error while mounting app: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')
    at _sfc_main.setup (root.vue:17:16)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7109:29)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7064:11)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4951:13)
    at hydrateNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4153:21)
    at hydrate2 (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4068:9)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3900:25)
    at Object.app.mount (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1612:20)
    at initApp (entry.mjs:34:12)
(anonymous) @ entry.mjs:39
```

I have no idea how to fix this - I am entirely blocked and I am writing here as a last resort. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: do you have somewhere an variable or object named `modules`?

Comment: I have `.js` a file in in `/plugins` I am importing some clientside javascript from node_modules, but even removing this entire file did not have an impact. All occurrences of the word "module" only appear in relation to `node_modules`, and that `.js` file is the only nuxt-related occurrence. Everything else is lockfiles, package, etc.

Comment: Yeah, there is apparently a bit of a regression on that one. Feel free to wait a bit or downgrade to the RC1.